# Bootstrap columns in a row overlap with thymeleaf image tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I have a div contains a row with 2 columns. Left column contains an image and right side contains some text. I've tried 100s of different combinations but couldn't figure out how to avoid overlapping problem. As you can see the images, when I start to resize the window, it starts to overlapping.

```
<div class="py-5">
    <section class="my-5"><!-- Section -->
        <div class="container"><!-- Container -->
            <div class="row"><!-- Grid row -->

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <img th:src="@{/img/about.jpg}" src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

                <!-- Grid column -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <!-- Section heading -->
                    <h1 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold mb-4">About Us</h1>
                    <!-- Section description -->
                    <p class="lead grey-text mx-auto">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                        electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                        the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                        including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Grid column -->

            </div><!-- Grid row -->
        </div><!-- Container -->
    </section><!-- Section -->
</div>
```

[image: Large]

[image: Medium]

[image: Medium 2]

[image: Small]

I would love to have some margin top when its small as well, to have a clear separation.

**UPDATE**

Ryan Maffey, your solution works good up until a certain point. This is the result just before going for mobile view. Looks so bad at this point. I would love to have image on its own row if it shrinks more than 50%. Is it possible?

[image: Limit for md view]

**UPDATE 2**

I finally found the combination I was looking for. This result solved all my problems.

```
<div>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 my-4">
                    <img style="width: 100%;" th:src="@{/img/about.jpg}" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 my-4">
                    <h1 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold mb-4">Header</h1>
                    <p class="lead grey-text mx-auto">Lorem ipsum...</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the image is overflowing the column.

Adding CSS `width: 100%` onto the image will mean that it is only ever as wide as the width of the column it's in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ryan, I updated my question with the result

Answer (score 0):

In the Mobile view you need to center the image vertically. Just use the parent div's style of that image to `display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;` and that image to `vertical-align: middle; max-height: 100px;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the result is the same.